# Can RSpec ignore checking port number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I wrote a simple spec:

```
visit root_url
click_button 'Sign in'

expect(current_url).to eq user_sign_in_url
```

and run this spec, it fails because of following:

```
expected: "http://example.com/users/sign_in"
     got: "http://example.com:12345/users/sign_in"
```

Why in this case RSpec checked port number?
Can RSpec ignore checking this? Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you use `current_path`?  Eg: `expect(current_path).to eq user_sign_in_path`

Comment: Are you using Capybara? Is `Capybara.server_port` set to 12345?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use `current_path` method instead of `current_url`, because the second one returns the whole url. Another thing is that you are asserting strings (expect `current_url` to equal some string). This is totally okay in most of the cases, but more safe method is to use `have_current_path` like this:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(...)
```

It will ensure to complete all preceding actions like `click_button`.